# Cropping the first element in a string array without copying all the elements to a new array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

Have a string array

```
string[] lines
```

I would like to remove the first element. So if the array has 5 elements, I want to end up with 4.

There is a number of ways to achieve this:

1. Create a new string array, with the same size as the original minus one. Then simply copy all elements (except the first one). I don't like this because, well, you have to make whole new array and seemingly duplicate the memory usage (?)
2. Use a collection like `List` that implements methods for this. But then it would be the same story: I would have to convert my string array to a list, then remove the first element, then convert the list to a string array (because I need a string array, not a list).
3. `System.Array.Resize()` seems to be capable of "cropping" arrays, which is precisely what I need. However, it crops the "rightmost" elements, whereas I need to crop the first (leftmost) element instead.

---

My question is: is there a simpler way to eliminate the first element in a string array, ending up with an array whose size is one less than the original's?

Comment: AFAIK array's are immutable. `System.Array.Resize()` does so by using option 1.

Comment: If you really need this, you probably want a CircularBuffer.  There are plenty of C# implementations around as google will attest.

Comment: Nope.. you can't do it without copying.. Best you can do is (), create a custom class, which

Comment: @JamesBarrass Exactly. For that reason the parameter to the `Resize<>` method is `ref T[] array`; the `ref` (`IsByRef`) would not have been needed if the existing instance was kept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what you want to use the "cropped" version for, but a very cheap thing to do is top wrap `lines` in an `ArraySegment<>`, like this:

```
  var cropped = new ArraySegment<string>(lines, 1, 4);
```

Since .NET 4.5 (from 2012), `ArraySegment<>` implements some interfaces, so you can do things like:

```
  foreach (var l in cropped)
  {
      // ...
  }
```

(uses an explicit interface implementation on `ArraySegment<>`, the iteration variable `l` is strongly typed).

Remember that this is just a wrapper around the original array instance. If that array is modified, this is reflected in the `ArraySegment<>`. There was no copying (not even a shallow one).

---

If you need indexing and so on, box the value of your `ArraySegment<>` struct to either `IReadOnlyList<>` or `IList<>`:

```
  IReadOnlyList<string> croppedB = new ArraySegment<string>(lines, 1, 4);
```

or:

```
  IList<string> croppedC = new ArraySegment<string>(lines, 1, 4);
```

Comment: That's neat, that struct didn't make any sense prior to .NET 4.5 because it simply carried around the offset and length, and you had to do the offset calculation yourself. I wonder why they didn't create a constructor which takes a `IList<T>` to allow nesting them. Making a completely readonly variant would have made even more sense, IMHO.

Comment: +1 for ArraySegment. You never stop learning. May come in handy eventually, thx.

Answer (score 2):

If you are really into this whole "don't create a new array" you could use a startIndex and length variables and always have your whole array as it was and only mark a part of it as usable via those two values. But if you aren't into large array sizes and on-the-edge performance, your program will look a lot cleaner, will be easier to understand, create and maintain if you just create a new array:

```
var arrayMinusFirstElement = lines.Skip(1).ToArray()
```

Comment: this is not  "eliminating the first element in a array".

Comment: @HamidP No, because eliminating an element from an array without creating temporaries is by definition impossible. An array is fixed. You can use the way I described or use the code I posted if temporaries are fine. Any other solution (including yours) is just hiding the creation of temporaries. But *hiding* it was not the point of the question, the OP asked about *avoiding* it.

Comment: how my solution is hiding "creating of temporaries" ?

Comment: @HamidP you have a whole dictionary as temporary storage. The OP has an array before the operation and needs an array after the operation.

Answer (score 1):

this solution is simulating an array, you can add items at the end and crop items from begin.
you can always use zero based indexer no matter how many items you have added or cropped.
It is a queue which you can modify it's elements and accessing them by their index.

```
var lines = new DicAsArray<string>();
lines.Add("zero");
lines.Add("one");
lines.Add("two");
lines.Add("three");
lines.Add("four");
lines.Crop();
lines[2] = "!!!";

for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(lines[i]);
}
```

and the rest is like

```
public class DicAsArray<T>
{
    public DicAsArray()
    {
        _dic = new Dictionary<int, T>();
        _minIndex = 0;
        _maxIndex = -1;
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        _dic[++_maxIndex] = item;
    }

    public T Crop()
    {
        _croppedCount++;
        var item = _dic[_minIndex];
        _dic.Remove(_minIndex++);
        return item;
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            var mappedIndex = _croppedCount + index;
            return _dic[mappedIndex];
        }
        set
        {
            var mappedIndex = _croppedCount + index;
            if (mappedIndex > _maxIndex || mappedIndex < _minIndex)
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            _dic[mappedIndex] = value;
        }
    }

    public int Count { get { return _dic.Count; } }

    private Dictionary<int, T> _dic;
    private int _maxIndex;
    private int _minIndex;
    private int _croppedCount;
}
```

Comment: Posting code without an accompanying explanation is discouraged on Stack Overflow. You might, for example, mention how incredibly inefficient this implementation is, compared to a `Queue<T>`. Also, it's probably `_dic.Remove(_minIndex++)`?

Comment: I'm on my way, wait a sec.

Comment: it is not a `Queue`, `Queue` does not have indexer. @Groo

Comment: But does this really mean you have to use a `Dictionary` to store a segment of an array? Do you know how `Queue<T>` is implemented in .NET (or, well, in any library I can think of)?

Comment: yes, it is implementation is backed by an array and two variable for maintaining head and tail indexes. this is not storing a segment of array, I implemented an array like structure that items can be added at the tail, items can be cropped form it's head and it maintains the indexes no matter what you have done. and you can also access and modify each item by it's index @Groo

Comment: No matter what transformations you are doing with the indexes, you still don't need a dictionary for that. And OP doesn't want to keep indexes from the original collection, he simply wants to know if there is a way to have an indexable collection which supports efficient dequeue operations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64378/discussion-between-hamidp-and-groo).

Answer (score 0):

You say `Array.Resize()` crops the rightmost element, then simply reverse the array first and then reverse it after.

`Array.Reverse(Array.Resize(Array.Reverse(myArray)))`